# Change the Text color of Spinner Using Textwatcher

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-textwatcher

Hi I want to change the Spinner text color using the text watcher.Spinner text should change color based on the character entered in edittext or empty edittext.

```
    <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/displacement"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight=".15"
                android:entries="@array/array_metric_piston"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingEnd="1dp"
                android:paddingStart="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/editext_green"

 />
```

Tried as below but not working

```
 if(charSequence.length() >0 ) {


                    spin_motor_displacement.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onGlobalLayout() {
                            ((TextView) spin_motor_displacement.getRootView()).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        }
                    });

}
```

Comment: Solved Using the below line code in textWatcher   ((TextView) spin_motor_power.getSelectedView()).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray_1));

Answer (score 0):

add this custom adapter in your code

```
public class adapter_spinner_steuer extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    public adapter_spinner_steuer(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        arrayList = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView tv = (TextView) view;
        if (position == 0) {
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#0015ff"));
            ;
        } else {
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7178c6"));
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        if (position == 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return getCustomView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    public View getCustomView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(URL.this).inflate(R.layout.public_spinner_item, parent, false);
        TextView label =  view.findViewById(R.id.spinner_textView);
        label.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        if (this.isEnabled(position)) {
            label.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#7178c6"));
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

and dont forget to call it:

```
       final ArrayAdapter<String> url_spinnerArrayAdapter = new adapter_spinner_steuer(URL.this, R.layout.public_spinner_item, url_array);
    url_spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.public_spinner_item);
    spinner_url.setAdapter(url_spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Comment: scoot i don't want to change the colors in drop down just the default spinner item

Comment: create public_spinner_item layout and inside it use this :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/spinner_textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="@color/red"
    android:textSize="14sp" />

Comment: This will change the color of the default text that appear on spinner before u select any of its options.

Comment: yeah now when the app start the spinner will be default red color. Now my requirement is when i enter some characters in the edittext the spinner defult text color should change to green without touching the spinner.